# Why am I getting different results via LINQ to Entities that via run of SQL generated by the same query?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I'm working on a school project that was started by another group last semester. This semester I'm on a team that is tasked with completing this project. There are ZERO common people between the groups .... my team is a completely new team attempting to finish another teams project with little to no documentation.

Anyway, with that background out of the way, I am having an issue with the project. My entity framework seems to not like the views I have created. It may also be worth mentioning that when creating this view, it is a complex view and was created by joining about 6-7 tables

As an arbitrary test (i dont really need answers that have "what" in them), I have executed this query in **SQL Management Studio**

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Course_Answers_Report] -- Course_Answers_Report is a View
WHERE question like '%what%'
```

Which produces the following output:

```
survey_setup_id | course_number | crn_number | term_offered |        course_title           | Instructor_Name    | question_type_id |                   question                           | answer
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2617            |    107013     |    5001    |    201505    |  Advanced Microsoft Access    | -output ommited-   |      2           | I  understood what the teacher was saying.           |    A
2617            |    107013     |    5001    |    201505    |  Advanced Microsoft Access    | -output ommited-   |      2           | I can apply what I learned in this class.            |    A
2617            |    107013     |    5001    |    201505    |  Advanced Microsoft Access    | -output ommited-   |      2           | I understood what was expected of me in this course. |    A
```

---

Now in  **Visual Studio** i have this small bit of code (as a small side note this is in MVC, however the issue doesn't lie in MVC, but rather somewhere in the LINQ, Entity, or Controller.....this has been decided by doing some debugging).

```
public ActionResult modelTest()
{
        using (SurveyEntities context = new SurveyEntities())
        {
                context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

                var questions = context
                                .Course_Answers_Report
                                .Where(r => r.question.Contains("what"))
                                .ToList();

                ViewBag.Questions = questions;
         }
}
```

This outputs the following table on the View (again, the problem is decidedly not in the View because when debugging, the var that holds the List has all incorrect data)

```
survey_setup_id | course_number | crn_number | term_offered |        course_title           | Instructor_Name    | question_type_id |                   question                           | answer
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2617            |    107013     |    5001    |    201505    |  Advanced Microsoft Access    | -output ommited-   |      2           | I understood what the teacher was saying.            |    A
2617            |    107013     |    5001    |    201505    |  Advanced Microsoft Access    | -output ommited-   |      2           | I understood what the teacher was saying             |    A
2617            |    107013     |    5001    |    201505    |  Advanced Microsoft Access    | -output ommited-   |      2           | I understood what the teacher was saying.            |    A
```

As you can see, this output is incorrect as the question (or rather the record) never changes when it should be

The SQL generated by this linq statement is

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[survey_setup_id] AS [survey_setup_id], 
[Extent1].[course_number] AS [course_number], 
[Extent1].[crn_number] AS [crn_number], 
[Extent1].[term_offered] AS [term_offered], 
[Extent1].[course_title] AS [course_title], 
[Extent1].[Instructor_Name] AS [Instructor_Name], 
[Extent1].[question_type_id] AS [question_type_id], 
[Extent1].[question] AS [question], 
[Extent1].[answer] AS [answer]
FROM (SELECT 
[Course_Answers_Report].[survey_setup_id] AS [survey_setup_id], 
[Course_Answers_Report].[course_number] AS [course_number], 
[Course_Answers_Report].[crn_number] AS [crn_number], 
[Course_Answers_Report].[term_offered] AS [term_offered], 
[Course_Answers_Report].[course_title] AS [course_title], 
[Course_Answers_Report].[Instructor_Name] AS [Instructor_Name], 
[Course_Answers_Report].[question_type_id] AS [question_type_id], 
[Course_Answers_Report].[question] AS [question], 
[Course_Answers_Report].[answer] AS [answer]
FROM [dbo].[Course_Answers_Report] AS [Course_Answers_Report]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[question] LIKE N'%what%'
```

---

When this SQL is run inside SQL management studio, it produces proper results. I am at a loss as to why EF is behaving this way, can anyone offer insight

EDIT: Per request of Danny Varod, the EDMX can be found here **http://pastebin.com/dUf6J4fV** and the View can be found here **http://pastebin.com/sCsqNYWc** (the view is kind of ugly/sloppy as it was just supposed to be a test and experiment)

Comment: Not enough details - missing view and underlaying table details, EDMX or Code First mappings.

Comment: EDMX can be found here http://pastebin.com/dUf6J4fV

View can be found here http://pastebin.com/sCsqNYWc (kind of ugly as it was just supposed to be a test and experiment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is visible in the edmx file;

> warning 6002: The table/view 'wctcsurvey.dbo.Course_Answers_Report' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.

```
<EntityType Name="Course_Answers_Report">
<Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="survey_setup_id" />
</Key>
```

You have not defined a primary key in the table, so one has been "guessed". Since the guessed column `survey_setup_id` is not unique in the table (all 3 rows in the correct result have the same value), EF will get confused and fetch the same object 3 times (it has the same guessed primary key after all).

If you add a correct primary key annotation to your model (ie a unique field), the problem will disappear.

Comment: How can that be done when using a view though? SQL Views are for the most part in essence, keyless

Comment: Huh, well I guess I just add an "Entity Key" to the entity huh? something that helps mark it unique.....It has nothing to really do with SQL primary and composite keys now does it? :) .Thanks!